# CORS issue on php built api

Tags: php, ajax, cors

I have built php api to exchange data but it cause CORS issue on my web app.
It returns proper data on postman request but not on the web app.
[image: error message on console]

I tried add below code on the back-end

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
```

[image: added code]

But it give me same error message.

Below is the header on postman response.

[image: header on postman response]

The header contain CORS setting on postman response but still not working.
Is there any other ways to fix it?

---

I tried several method for request data

1.

```
axios.get("localhost:1234/getSingersJson.php?test=[144]")
```

2. 

```
var url = "localhost:1234/getSingersJson.php"; 
var params = "[144]"; 
const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xmlhttp.onload = function(){ 
    console.log(this.responseText); 
} 
xmlhttp.open("GET", url + "?test=" + params); 
xmlhttp.send();
```

3. 

```
fetch(url + "?test=" + params) 
.then(response => { 
    if(!response.ok) { 
        throw Error(response.statusText); 
    } 
    console.log(response) 
})
```

---

Exact error message for each codes are like below.

```
function api_test(){
    var url = "https://localhost:1234/getSingersJson.php";
    var params = "[144]";
    
    fetch(url + "?test=" + params) 
    .then(response => { 
        if(!response.ok) { 
            throw Error(response.statusText); 
        } 
        console.log(response) 
    })
}
```

[image]

```
function api_test(){
    var url = "https://localhost:1234/getSingersJson.php";
    var params = "[144]";
    
    const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onload = function(){
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url + "?test=" + params);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

[image]

---

Network tab in developer tool is as below.

[image]

And request tab and response tab shows nothing.

---

**Previously I've running it on my local test server. I upload the php file on my AWS server and it works OK.**

Comment: It seems that primarily you actually have a network error, although it would help a lot if we could see your axios code and your error handling code.

Comment: Can you share your xhr request?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69768920/edit) to include any code you want to share with us and use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to ensure it's presented clearly . As you can see for yourself, it is very hard to read in the comments. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. Do you get the exact same error from all those attempts? Or different ones each time? It would help to have full clarity.

Comment: I've got same error every time.

Comment: are you using any framework like Laravel or is it core php? and version?

Comment: Did you really get the Network error every time? Because according to the screenshot, that error is generated by Axios specifically. Did you get an alternative error instead of that, in the XHR and fetch cases?

Comment: I added exact error messages but I think core reason would be same. @sid the api is made by core php

Comment: Ok thanks. Have you examined the Network tool in your browser to see what the request actually returned, including headers? I think you should be able to see it.

Comment: I tried request by postman and it gives me proper data as I posted. It contains CORS header as well(Please see picture 3)

Comment: Testing in Postman is less relevant since only cross-domain AJAX requests are subject to CORS restrictions. Those restrictions therefore do not apply to PostMan requests. It's nice to have the confirmation from Postman that the PHP code basically works ok, but to help figure out the CORS issue it would be useful to use your browser's Network tool, as I mentioned. Then we know what's happening in the browser, not in Postman.

Comment: I added screenshot for the network tool. I hope this is thing you said.

Comment: Well I asked for _response_ headers and the content of the Response tab (if any). You've shown request headers only. So it's close, but not quite everything.

Comment: But...there was something useful: your Origin appears to be the same hostname and port as the request destination, only the protocol is different. So really this request needn't be subject to CORS at all, if you access your page via HTTPS (just like you're trying to access the AJAX request via HTTPS), or alternatively access the AJAX via HTTP (just like your page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Origin` appears to be the same hostname and port as the request destination, only the protocol is different (HTTP vs HTTPS).

So really this request needn't be subject to CORS at all, if you access your page via HTTPS (just like you're trying to access the AJAX request via HTTPS), or alternatively access the AJAX via HTTP (just like your page).

Once the protocol, hostname/domain and port are the same for both the main page and the AJAX URL, they're considered to be the "same origin", and therefore [CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) restrictions do not apply.

Comment: Previously I've running it on my local test server. I upload the php file on my AWS server and it works. Holy moly..... Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

Try to send your XHR Request with Credentials?

`axios.get('your api url', {withCredentials: true});`

withCredentials() causes your browser to include cookies and authentication headers in your XHR request. If your service depends on a cookie (including session cookies), it will only work with this option.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it gives me same error. I also tried add "crossdomain:true" but not working.

Comment: @Young-KwangOh ok. What else comes to mind in this regard. Can you delete your cookies first? Is your frontend on the same domain or subdomain as your api server?

Comment: Yes. Currently both files are running on my local test server.

Comment: I've clear the issue. Thank you for helping me